# Jquery Wrap divs with parent div within $.each

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap each object which will contain a group of `div.field`(s) with a parent div `.row`.  Jquery is only allowing me to open and close the parent div on the same line.  Please help!

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('WF-XML.php', function(data) {

        JSON.stringify(data);
        var prevCardCode = '';

        $.each( data, function(index, element){

            if (!(element['CardCode'] == prevCardCode)) {

                var sum = element['payment_sum'];

                    $('#showdata').append('<div class="row"><div class="field">' + sum + '</div>');
                }
                prevCardCode = element['CardCode'];

                $.each(element, function(i, element_detail){
                    if (!(i == 'InvKey' || i == 'PostDate' || i == 'City' || i == 'Objtype' || i == 'Block' || i == 'ZipCode' || i == 'Address' || i == 'payment_sum' || i == 'State1' || i == 'Country' || i == 'NumAtCard')) {
                        var detail = element_detail;
                        $('#showdata').append('<div class="field">' + detail + '</div>');
                    }

                });

           });
    });

});
```

PHP

```
  if (($handle = fopen('upload/BEN-new.csv', "r")) === FALSE) {
    die('Error opening file'); 
 }

 $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
 $complete = array();

      while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",")) {
       $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
        }
    fclose($handle);

    echo json_encode($complete);
```

Here is the data:

```
 {"InvKey":"11704","CardCode":"1611704", "payment_sum": "1055.40"},
 {"InvKey":"11703","CardCode":"1611703", "payment_sum": "550.00"}
```

Its printing like this:

```
 <div class="row">
      div class="field">1055.40</div>
 </div>
 <div class="field">1611704</div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="field">550.00</div>
 </div>
 <div class="field">1611703</div>
```

I would like it to print like this:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="field">1055.40</div>
      <div class="field">1611704</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="field">550.00</div>
      <div class="field">1611703</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here.  What are you trying to wrap with what?  Which line is giving you problems?

Comment: I am trying to wrap class field(s) with class row.  But not each div, only each group of divs every time the loop restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for certain but I think you want something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('WF-XML.php', function(data) {
        var prevCardCode = '';
        $.each( data, function(index, element){
            if (element['CardCode'] !== prevCardCode) {
                //var newDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('row').appendTo('#showdata');
                var newDiv = $('<div class="rowGroup"><div class="row"></div></div>').appendTo('#showdata').find('.row');
                $('<div class="field">' + element['payment_sum'] + '</div>').appendTo(newDiv);
                $.each(element, function(key, val) {
                    if (key !== 'InvKey' && key !== 'PostDate' && key !== 'payment_sum') {
                        $('<div class="field">' + val + '</div>').appendTo(newDiv);
                    }
                });
                prevCardCode = element['CardCode'];
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @user1413248, I just edited in a correction and an improvement to prevent payment_sum appearing twice.

Comment: Thank you! How would I add another parent div around each set of fields?

Comment: Another? You mean double-wrapped?

Comment: Well there are times when there are multiple sets of .field groups within .row and I need to style it with css..

Comment: Answer edited to provide an alternative line starting `newDiv = ...`. This will give you a `rowGroup` wrapper but as the rest of the code stands, each rowGroup will only ever have one row. Further mods will be necessary to get multiple rows per rowGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `<div class="field">` elements to the `<div class="row">` element.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('WF-XML.php', function(data) {

        JSON.stringify(data); // NOTE: This doesn't do anything!!
        var prevCardCode = '';
        var newDiv;

        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            if (element['CardCode'] != prevCardCode) {
                newDiv = $('<div class="row">').appendTo('#showdata');
                var sum = element['payment_sum'];
                $('.field').before(newDiv);
                $(newDiv).append('<div class="field">' + sum + '</div>');
            }
            prevCardCode = element['CardCode'];

            $.each(element, function(i, element_detail) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 'InvKey':
                    case 'PostDate':
                    case 'City':
                    case 'Objtype':
                    case 'Block':
                    case 'ZipCode':
                    case 'Address':
                    case 'payment_sum':
                    case 'State1':
                    case 'Country':
                    case 'NumAtCard':
                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    default:
                        $(newDiv).append('<div class="field">' + element_detail + '</div>');
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I also cleaned up your code in a few places (fixed indentation and made your long condition easier to read).

An alternative approach would be to build a **string** containing the HTML you want to insert into the document, and not use jQuery until the entire string is built.  As soon as you say `$('<div>')`, jQuery will create a div element in memory.  If you want to put things inside of the created element, you have to actually put them inside of it.

Comment: I tried that... It closes it right after the first field div is printed.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how jQuery works.  It would help a lot if you can post a fully working example on http://jsfiddle.net - that way we can correct it and point out exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the method of adding to a string?

Comment: Try now - I forgot to actually put the `newDiv` into the document.  As far as adding to a string... it doesn't get any simpler than that... just start a string with `<div class="row">` and add to it as you go, then insert the closing `</div>` tag at the end.

Comment: Thank you - but the code now just prints this:<div class="row">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="field">1055.40</div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>